# ie font-face rendering issue

Tags: css, cross-browser, font-face

im running @font-face on a site it works fine accross all browsers firefox, chrome, safari ect, but on ie(all versions by the looks of it) its falling short.

ive attached example images of whats happening bellow, its in firefox on the left (this is how it is in all other browsers) and in ie on the right

[image] [image]

this is the css that im using for the font-face

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'rll';
src: url('../type/rll.eot?') format('eot');
src: url('../type/rll.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
 url('../type/rll.woff') format('woff'),
 url('../type/rll.ttf') format('truetype'),
 url('../type/rll.svg') format('svg');
}
```

is there an obvious mistake ive made ? So i know which one is causing the problem, could you also let me know which font file ie uses ?

Comment: IE 8 and older use EOT, newer use WOFF. Where is the font from, and how did you generate the different formats?

Comment: to convert the file i used http://www.font2web.com/

Comment: Your code look good. use http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator for generating font face.

Comment: @sam, in order to analyze the problem, information about the source of the font (in order to replicate the situation) and/or a link to a page where the problem can be seen is needed. The HTML markup and the CSS code that uses the font may be relevant, too.